# How to override bootstrap css?

Tags: css, overrides, bootstrap

I would like to use the tooltip function of Bootstrap 3 on my website (www.fischer-club.ch). I tried to override the `margin-top` value in my custom.css to better place the tooltip:

```
.tooltip.top {
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

This doesn't work; the style from bootstrap.min.css remains.

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` after the pixel value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine but you have an error in `custom.css` file right before. `.btn-anmeldung` rule is missing a closing bracket:

```
/* Bouton Anmeldung sur la Homepage */
.btn-anmeldung {
  background-color:#777777;
  border-color:#555555;
  color:#FFFFFF;

/* Augmenter l'espace du tooltip de bootstrap */
.tooltip.top {
  margin-top: -40px;
  }
```

Add it and it works:

```
/* Bouton Anmeldung sur la Homepage */
.btn-anmeldung {
  background-color:#777777;
  border-color:#555555;
  color:#FFFFFF;
 }

/* Augmenter l'espace du tooltip de bootstrap */
.tooltip.top {
  margin-top: -40px;
  }
```